# Angular 5 select option value forced to string

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

I've defined a simple `select` bound to a variable like so:

```
<select id="client" name="client" [(ngModel)]="order.clientId">
    <option *ngFor="let client of clients" [value]="client.id">
        {{ client.name }}
    </option>
</select>
```

and the `clients` is a simple class with a numeric `id` value:

```js
export class NameAndId {
    id: number;
    name: string;

    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

So I would expect that the value is a number, not a string.  And the `order.clientId` is also defined as a number.  However, when I pass the `order` object through an `HttpClient` post call like so, it's encoding the value as a string:

```js
return this.http.post<HttpResponse<any>>(this.baseUrl, order, {observe: 'response'});
```

Why isn't it appearing as a numeric value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try ngValue instead of [value]

[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngvalueselect)